# How do electrons choose their way through nodes?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

Suppose I have a circuit, powered by some emf ($V$). If I put two resistors $R1$ and $R2$ of different resistances in parallel, the current at the node is divided following Kirchhoff's circuit laws. This is also following the "universal" rule for which all objects try to get to the lowest energy state, fine.

However, **how do single electrons in the current know which way to go?** If the node wires are of the same diameter, current will not simply divide by half, and still follow Kirchhoff's laws.

[image: circuit]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do electrons know which path to take in a circuit?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33621/)