# How electrons are shared in parallel resistance circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrons, electrical-resistance, conductors

In parallel resistance circuit. When electrons are shared in both the parallel resistor (different values of both resistors) .when the electrons are just to shared how did they know what resistor they have? How they know to split in both the resistance?

For example, one is 3Ω and other 6Ω and the battery has 18Volts. Therefore, in 3A current will flow  from 6Ω and other resistance 6A will flow

How electrons in the form of current know what resistance they will face?

Comment: When a voltage is applied to an electric circuit, the electrons go from moving in totally random directions all the time, to moving totally random but with a *slighty* bias in the direction of decreasing potential. Remember, there are **many** electrons in wire, so on average they will flow according to the potential gradient where they are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do electrons know which path to take in a circuit?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/33621/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are at school? You have the wrong impression, that the electrons come from the batterie and "decide" how they will go, but the resistors are full of electrons wich can move.So you have the same situation with a pump for water (instead of the batterie) and to pipettes with different diameter, so the water has not to decide where to go but the pressure gets more through the thick pipe than trough the narrow one. Same with the electrons in the resistors, the batterie provides the voltage  or pressure.